# Go from One Input field to another in android

Tags: android

I have multiple text fields in my Android activity. When the user enters data in one text field and press enter, I want the cursor to move to another text field which is next to the current text field.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:nextFocusForward

Comment: Please post code to receive better responses

Answer (score 1):

You can use [android:nextFocusForward](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3anextFocusForward) to specify which view will receive focus after the action button is pressed, this is the default action button.